# Which Golden Chests am I Missing?

Tags: destiny

I've found walkthroughs for all the chest locations, and I know how to see how many chests I've gotten from each location. But is there a way to know, without actually having to go check each one, *which* chests I'm missing?

Right now I'm at 12/20 chests, but I don't have a clue which ones I've already picked up - so that's a fair bit of time I could save if there's a way to tell.

Comment: Be advised: there is also a bug which causes the triumphs counter to miss one or more of your chests.  I've seen several posts about it on bungie.net, and it happened to me: I had one character for which all planets reported 5/5, but the triumphs counter still said 19 of 20.   For me, the solution was to just finish out the chests on another character, but I've seen posts that that didn't help some people.

Comment: @CPerkins Thanks for the warning. I ended up just running through all the walkthroughs, prioritizing any areas that I was pretty sure I hadn't hit yet. Finished it and saw the MoT complete without a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By going to the map and to each planet, in the upper left corner I believe should be a "x/5 golden chests" that will tell you how many you've found. You are not able to find out which ones you've gotten except by visiting the locations.

Comment: There is no way to know exactly which chests you've got left besides the per-planet counter.

Comment: Yeah, I know about the per-planet counters. Was really hoping to get something a bit more detailed. :-(